# Me ayudan porfavor con los textarea

Tags: java

Estoy ingresando los divisores de un numero en un textarea

```
    int num=Integer.parseInt(txtnum.getText());

    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        if(num%i==0)
        {
            txtres1.append(String.valueOf(i+"\n"));
        }
    }
```

De esa lista de divisorios necesito sacar los numeros primos e ingresarlos a otro textarea.

Cuando quiero convertirlo a entero me aparece un exepcion, NumberFormatException

```
    int num2 = Integer.parseInt(txtres1.getText().toString());
    int cont = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= num2; i++) {
        for (int j = num2; j >= 1; j--) {
            if(i%j==0)
            {
                cont++;
            }
        }
        if(cont == 2)
        {
            txtres2.append(String.valueOf(i+"\n"));
        }
        cont = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Te esta diciendo que hay un error al pasar de texto a numero, tienes un ejemplo de lo que introduces en el textarea, de igual manera ese toString creo que sobra, ya que getText retorna un string

Comment: oye amigo gracias por contestar. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que no pase ese error?

Comment: No ha contestado, esta zona es para comentarios. Por favor pon ejemplos de tus entradas para poder ayudarte, o en caso de que sea la iniciar el código de tu text area; siempre trata de poner un [mcve], es decir... que compile, que se vea tu problema allí, que dice exactamente tu mensaje de error, en que línea, o si no hay error como sale y como quisieras que saliera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es mejor usar un sistema frontend y backend siempre que se pueda.

En este sentido, las interfaces gráficas son el frontend. Y toda la logística del programa es mejor separarla, y llevarla por un backend.

Esto, aplicado al ejercicio significa que los datos que se sacan a tu JTextArea no deben de ser los únicos que existan luego para trabajar con ellos. Es mejor que, a parte de los datos que saques al JTextArea, esos datos los guardes en, por ejemplo, una variable. Un Array, un ArrayList, lo que quieras. Así es más facil luego pasar la información de un sitio a otro dentro de tu programa.

Por supuesto, habrá veces que necesites acceder a los datos que hay en un jtextArea porque es el único sitio donde los tienes, como por ejemplo cuando son introducidos ahí por el usuario. Pero este no es el caso.

Comment: Gracias amigo, guarde los datos en un ArrayList como dijiste y funciono, gracias.